# Confidence matrix for multilayer perceptron

Tags: java, neural-network, ignite

**Use case:** I have data which has 5 category of labels(output). I want to get the prediction confidence for the output.
Is there a way to get confidence matrix while doing prediction?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean it's classification problem? What algorithm do you use? If it's a classification then you're talking about confusion matrix not confidence matrix, right?

Comment: Yes....Confusion matrix.. I am using MultiLayer percepton algo for classification